# Put Hyperlink inside VBA Code for automatic emails

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I created a VBA Code inwhic it autmatically sends an email. In that email, I would like to have a hyperlink which links to a webpage where I uploaded a file.

The trouble I am having is putitng the HTML Hyperlink tags inside the VBA Code.

Check out my code:

```
msgbody = "Hi Everyone" & "<br> <br>" _
& "I have attached the excel file to this afternoon's Open Order Report above, as well as provided the link below:" & "<br> <br>" _
& "Please reach out if you have any more questions or concerns" & "<br>"
& "<a href= & "www.google.com">" & "link" </a>"

With objemail
    .to = "spall@.its.jnj.com"
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = "test"
    .htmlbody = msgbody
    .display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224280/adding-hyperlinks-to-excel-email-body-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hyperlinks to excel email body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224280/adding-hyperlinks-to-excel-email-body-text)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
& "<a href= & "www.google.com">" & "link" </a>"
```

with this

```
& "<a href=" & """" & "www.google.com" & """" & ">" & "link" </a>"
```