# Adding hyperlinks to Outlook Email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink

I made the codes below using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224280/adding-hyperlinks-to-excel-email-body-text) as reference:

```
Dim chartPath As String
Dim messageA As String
Dim hyperlink As String

'Set chart path
    chartPath = Environ("userprofile") & _
        "\Documents\Chart " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".png"

'Set hyperlink
hyperlink = www.google.com


 'Set message A
 messageA = "<p style= 'font-family:arial;font-size:12'>" & "<b>" & Range("E17").Value & "</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & Range("E18").Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & Range("E19").Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & Range("E20").Value & " " & **"<b>" & "<u>" & "<a href =" & hyperlink & ">" & Range("E21").Value & "</a>" & "</u>" & "</b>"** & " " & Range("E22").Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>" & "<u>" & Range("E23").Value & "</u>" & "</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "</p>"

With OutlookMailItem
     .HTMLBody = messageA & "<img src ='" & chartPath & "'>"
End With
```

However, the text which contains hyperlink does not direct me to the website once click and I think, using string for this part is the problem. What could be the possible remedy for this

Comment: there is an extra space in the hyperlink sytnax. use `"<a href=" & hyperlink & ">"`

Comment: Oh! that extra space was the reason for the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to run your code but I found that these 2 lines should have some changes:

```
'Set hyperlink
hyperlink = "www.google.com" 'Added ""
'Also you can set the value from a cell.
hyperlink = Cells(1,1).Value 'Get value from cell A1.

 'Set message A - Removed **
messageA = "<p style= 'font-family:arial;font-size:12'>" & "<b>" & Range("E17").Value & "</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & Range("E18").Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & Range("E19").Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & Range("E20").Value & " " & "<b>" & "<u>" & "<a href =" & hyperlink & ">" & Range("E21").Value & "</a>" & "</u>" & "</b>" & " " & Range("E22").Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>" & "<u>" & Range("E23").Value & "</u>" & "</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "</p>"
```

Please test your code again.

Comment: I've tried adding " " and it worked. What if this hyperlink value is taken from the specific cell in excel? Will it still be "<a href=" & hyperlink & ">" ? Thanks

Comment: You can specify the `hyperlink` value from a cell. I edited my post, please review the example. If this answer solved your problem, please mark ask solved. :)

Comment: i guess, using strings causes errors on my macro. Instead of using "<a href=" & hyperlink & ">", I've changed the word hyperlink with its complete value and it totally worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change this line `hyperlink = www.google.com` to this: `hyperlink = "http://www.google.com"`

If your URL has spaces in it, those need to be replaced with `%20` - This code will convert it for you:

```
hyperlink = Replace(hyperlink, " ", "%20")
```

Comment: Is there a limit in the length for link? As observed, I've changed the value for my hyperlink with a long one and it did not get the complete link that I've indicated. Is that really how it works?

Comment: There should be no limit to the length of the URL. Keep in mind if it has any spaces in it, those need to be replaced with `%20`.